# Can't import bare git project into eclipse via ssh

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh

I have recently set up a web server to which a user has ssh access. I created a new git repository on the server by doing the following:

```
user@server/dev:~$ git init --bare project.git
```

I am trying to import the project into my local eclipse instance, connecting using ssh. I have entered the following options:

```
ssh://user@host.com:1234/dev/project.git
```

Using the valid username and password in the options for "user". However, when I try to connect it fails to do so, but if I try and ssh to that directory as the same user via command line then I am able to get there.

What do I need to do to get the git project working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. You have to use the absolute pathname rather than a user's relative one.

```
ssh://user@host.com:1234/home/user/dev/project.git
```